# civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 to 5.3.1 from 4.7.30

Tags: upgrade

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Your database is marked with an unexpected version number: 5.2.2. The automated upgrade to version 4.7.30 can not be run - and the 4.7.30 codebase may not be compatible with your database state. You will need to determine the correct version corresponding to your current database state. You may want to revert to the codebase you were using prior to beginning this upgrade until you resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by putting back the right version and doing reset. The doing the upgrade to 5.3.1.